# SessionStorage in Chrome is not displayed anymore in version 119.0.5933.70

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just got the newest version of Chrome and when I navigate to dev tools, I cannot see my .net session variables anymore. Anyone else noticing the same problem? solutions all appreciated.

Cleared all cache, restarted laptop and Chrome browser, no luck,
I'm expecting to see the Session variable I stored with .net Controller:
Session["mysessionvariable"] = true;

Tried setting other variables in other Controllers no luck.
Also tried Retrieving the variable via code and it is in session, it just does not show in Chrome.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to retrieve the variables? Session data in ASP.NET is stored server-side and is mapped using a session cookie, so I am confused as to exactly how you're achieving this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jhmckimm, I'm curious now how do you set session variables?    .net has always been:
SET a variable:   Session["mysessionvariable"] = true;  GET the variable:  var myvar = Session["mysessionvariable"];   and that's not the issue, I can get the variable.   the Problem is I cannot no longer see it in Chrome Browser with the Chrome latest updates.

Comment: My point is that you should not be able to see these variables in the browser - the data within the session is stored server-side. You must've been exposing that data to the browser some other way.

Comment: @RobertCarlson please see the accepted answer on the that question. Client-side session state is different from server-side session variables

Comment: yeah, not sure what the heck was I thinking!!!  but now curious what the heck?
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/sessionstorage/